# Difficulty with edge-case with pathfinding grid generation

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, path-finding, a-star

I'm attempting to develop an implementation of [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/175384) for supporting A-star path-finding for units that are potentially larger than a single cell.

The issue I'm having is that there is a small error in my output at the moment, and I'm not sure if I'm implementing it improperly, or if the algorithm does not handle this edge-case properly.

Here is a full-reproduction demonstrating the problem:

```js
function createThickGrid(inputGrid, width, height) {
    let outputGrid = [];

    let largeInteger = 100000000;

    for (let i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
        if (inputGrid[i] === 0) { // wall
            outputGrid[i] = -1;
        } else {
            outputGrid[i] = largeInteger;
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
        if (outputGrid[i] > 0) {
            outputGrid[i] = getSmallestNeighbor(outputGrid, i, width, height) + 2;
        }
    }

    return outputGrid;
}

function getSmallestNeighbor(grid, idx, width, height) {
    let col = idx % width;
    let row = Math.floor(idx / width);

    let smallest = 99999999999999;

    if (row <= 0 || row >= height - 1 || col <= 0 || col >= width - 1) {
        return -1;
    }

    let northValue = grid[idx - width];
    if (northValue < smallest) {
        smallest = northValue;
    }

    let northWestValue = grid[idx - width - 1];
    if (northWestValue < smallest) {
        smallest = northWestValue;
    }

    let northEastValue = grid[idx - width + 1];
    if (northEastValue < smallest) {
        smallest = northEastValue;
    }

    let southValue = grid[idx + width];
    if (southValue < smallest) {
        smallest = southValue;
    }

    let southWestValue = grid[idx + width - 1];
    if (southWestValue < smallest) {
        smallest = southWestValue;
    }

    let southEastValue = grid[idx + width + 1];
    if (southEastValue < smallest) {
        smallest = southEastValue;
    }

    let westValue = grid[idx - 1];
    if (westValue < smallest) {
        smallest = westValue;
    }

    let eastValue = grid[idx + 1];
    if (eastValue < smallest) {
        smallest = eastValue;
    }

    return smallest;
}

// You can ignore this, it's just for pretty printing
function convert1DTo2D(grid, width, height) {
    let arr = [];

    for (let row = 0; row < height; row++) {

        let newRow = [];

        for (let col = 0; col < width; col++) {
            newRow.push(grid[row * width + col]);
        }

        arr.push(newRow);
    }

    return arr;
}

let width = 5;
let height = 5;

// 0 == wall and 1 == free space

grid = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

let thickGrid = createThickGrid(grid, width, height);

// console table works better but I don't know if Stackoverflow supports it
// console.table(convert1DTo2D(thickGrid, width, height));

console.log(convert1DTo2D(thickGrid, width, height));
```

As you can see, the output for the following is this:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 5, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 5, 3, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Which seems almost entirely correct except for the middle value of the second to last row. I believe that should be a `3` instead of a `5`.

These numbers refer to the half-tile distances between them and the nearest wall (in this case the nearest wall is the edges of the array). I believe instead it should be the following:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 5, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

But I'm not sure why it's not already like this. Is the algorithm wrong or is my implementation flawed?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, your algorithm will not work like that. When a distance is updated, this might affect the distance of a cell that you had already treated (north), which should be reduced in light of the distance the current cell just got.

An algorithm that works for tackling this problem is a bread-first traversal: this will make you visit a cell in order of its distance. So you start with the walls, find their neighbors and put those at the end of a queue. Process cells from the start of the queue. This way you will find the shortest path from a wall to any cell, and can correctly determine their distance.

There are several ways to implement this breadth-first traversal. I personally like to do this with two normal arrays instead of a single queue. Each time you have added all neighbors to an array, you make that array the basis of a next iteration where the distance will be 2 greater. The next iteration will populate a *new* array with neighbors. At the end of that iteration that new array is taken as the old array, and everything repeats until no more neighbors are found:

```js
function createThickGrid(inputGrid, width) {
    let height = inputGrid.length / width; // height can be derived...
    let outputGrid = [];

    // Add all walls to a list
    let wave = [-1]; // special wall value to denote the "wall" outside the grid
    for (let i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
        if (inputGrid[i] === 0) { // Wall
            outputGrid[i] = -1; // Mark wall in the output
            wave.push(i);
        }
    }
    let distance = 1;
    while (wave.length) { // Each iteration we deal with the next distance
        let nextWave = [];
        for (let i of wave) {
            // Collect unvisited neighbors of a cell
            let neighbors = getNeighbors(i);
            // Mark their distance
            for (let i of neighbors) outputGrid[i] = distance;
            // Schedule their treatment for next outer iteration
            nextWave.push(...neighbors);
        }
        // Prepare next iteration
        wave = nextWave;
        distance += 2;
    }
        
    return outputGrid;

    function getNeighbors(i) {
        let neighbors = [];
        if (i >= 0) { // normal case
            if (i % width) neighbors.push(i - 1 - width, i - 1, i - 1 + width);
            neighbors.push(i - width, i + width);
            if ((i+1) % width) neighbors.push(i + 1 - width, i + 1, i + 1 + width);
        } else { // all edge cells neighbor a "wall"
            neighbors = [...Array(width).keys(),
             ...Array.from({length: height-2}, (_,i) => (i + 1) * width),
             ...Array.from({length: height-2}, (_,i) => (i + 2) * width - 1),
             ...Array.from({length: width}, (_, i) => (height - 1) * width + i)
            ];
        }
        return neighbors.filter(i => 
            i >= 0 && i < width * height && outputGrid[i] === undefined
        );
    }
}

function convert1DTo2D(grid, width) {
    return Array.from({length: grid.length / width}, (_, i) =>
        grid.slice(i*width, (i+1)*width)
    );
}

let width = 5;
// 0 == wall and 1 == free space
let grid = [
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
];

let thickGrid = createThickGrid(grid, width);

for (let row of convert1DTo2D(thickGrid, width)) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is quite the algorithm. Thank you for all the work you put into this. There's a bit of a problem though (not with your solution, but something related..) What would happen if I would have to change one of the tiles? That is, say the player destroys a wall, and now it should be walkable. Will I have to re-compute the entire thick grid? Or is there a better way? Because I think if I have to recompute everything, then I probably won't be able to use this after all, due to performance reasons. Not sure if I should ask a separate question for this.

Comment: Imagine a grid of 1001x1001, with just one wall in the center. Removing that wall will have a huge impact on the grid, where you'll have to change 500x500 values. So even if there is a better method than recalculating everything, there will always be cases where a lot has to change. But yes, you could make this a new question.

Comment: Ah, that is very unfortunate. Hmm, maybe I should just make all entities in my game take up just one tile after all..